# How to share the same index among multiple dask arrays

Tags: dask

I'm trying to build a dask-based ipython application, that holds a meta-class which consists of some sub-dask-arrays (which are all shaped (n_samples, dim_1, dim_2 ...)) and should be able to sector the sub-dask-arrays by its **getitem** operator.

In the **getitem** method, I call the da.Array.compute method (the code is still in it's very early state), so I would be able to iterate batches of the sub-arrays.

```
def MetaClass(object):
    ...    
    def __getitem__(self, inds):
        new_m = MetaClass()
        inds = inds.compute()
        for name,var in vars(self).items():
            if isinstance(var,da.Array):
                try:
                    setattr(new_m, name, var[inds])
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
            else:
                setattr(new_m, name, var)
        return new_m

# Here I construct the meta-class to work with some directory.
m = MetaClass('/my/data/...')
# m.type is one of the sub-dask-arrays
m2 = m[m.type==2]
```

It works as expected, and I get the sliced arrays, but as a result I get a huge memory consumption, and I assume that in the background the mechanism of dask is copying the index for each sub-dask-array.

My question is, how do I achieve the same results, without using so much memory?

(I tried not to "compute" the "inds" in **getitem**, but then I get nan shaped arrays, which can not be iterated, which is a must for the application)

I have been thinking about three possible solutions that I'd be happy to be advised which of them is the "right" one for me. (or to get another solution which I haven't thought of):

1. To use a Dask DataFrame, which I'm not sure how to fit multidimensional-dask-arrays in (would really appreciate some help or even a link that explains how to deal with multidimensional arrays in dd).
2. To forget about the entire MetaClass, and to use one dask-array with a nasty dtype (something like [("type",int,(1,)),("images",np.uint8,(1000,1000))]), again, I'm not familiar with this and would really appreciate some help with that (tried to google it.. it's a bit complicated..)
3. To share the index as a global inside the calling function (**getitem**) with **property** and its get-function-mechanism (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property). But the big downside here is that I lose the types of the arrays (big down for representation and everything that needs anything but the data itself).

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use the sub-arrays.map_blocks with a shared function that holds the indices in its memory.

Here is an example:

```
        def bool_mask(arr, block_info=None):
            from_ind,to_ind = block_info[0]["array-location"][0]
            return arr[inds[from_ind:to_ind]]

        def getitem(var):
            original_chunks = var.chunks[0]
            tmp_inds = np.cumsum([0]+list(original_chunks))
            from_inds = tmp_inds[:-1]
            to_inds = tmp_inds[1:]
            new_chunks_0 = np.array(list(map(lambda f,t:inds[f:t].sum(),from_inds,to_inds)))
            new_chunks = tuple([tuple(new_chunks_0.tolist())] + list(var.chunks[1:]))
            return var.map_blocks(bool_mask,dtype=var.dtype,chunks=new_chunks)
```